# Settings Acitvity not returning to calling Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, preferenceactivity

**UPDATE**: The `finish()` after starting the Activity was the cause of this problem!

I have a Navigation Drawer Base Activity Class that all my other Activities (not SettingsActivity) inherit from.
The Back & Up-Button(ActionBar) both exit the App instead of navigating to the calling Activity.

The call to `SettingsActivity` is like this:

```
case DRAWER_ITEM_SETTINGS:
    startActivity(new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class));
    finish();
    break;
```

`AndroidManifest.xml` entry:

```
<activity
        android:name=".SettingsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_settings"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.example.MainActivity" />
</activity>
```

I was thinking that maybe the Context being the `BaseActivity` instead of lets say `ExampleActivty` that extends `BaseActivty` might be the problem? I've seen that the Google IO 2014 App calls their `SettingsActivity` in the same way though and it always returns to the calling Activity...

Comment: what do you mean by returning to calling activity? You should start activity using `startActivityForResult(intent)` and receive the result in the `onActivityResult()` of the calling acitivity.

Comment: but I don't really start the SettingsActivity for a result?

Comment: also with returning to calling Activity I mean that I want to start the Activity from which I opened the NavigationDrawer and started the SettingsActivity